# What is the function abc... on every site?

Tags: windows, function

On a lot of websites I see a script function abc... and a lot of stuff I can't quite understand. Can someone tell me what it is for?

```
(function (a,c,b){window[a].set(c,b)})("n8780519801657647", "4450222421437502", {"blockalert":false,"blockconfirm":false,"blockprompt":false,"renderalert":false});
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a complete lesson on Javascript, DHTML, and the DOM.  Try asking a smaller question, or at least tell us what parts you do understand (hint: there's no function named `abc` here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obfuscated code.

The real variable names have been changed to meaningless letters to make it harder for people to read.

As a commentor noted, this could also be to make the code smaller. I think that would still be considered obfuscation though; even if that wasn't the intent.

Comment: Probably so, although minification also replaces variable names with meaningless single letter names, because it makes the download smaller... but minification wouldn't use a function here.

Comment: @BenVoigt True. It's hard to tell exactly what it is given the small sample size.